# Hibernate TypeMismatchException - Provided id of the wrong type for class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am stuck with a hibernate issue since last Friday and really appreciate any help on this.

I am facing an issue with hibernate while doing a simple fetch query. I have two tables: `Trade` and `TradeDetails`. There is a `one-to-one` unidirectional relationship from Trade to Trade Details.

Table Structure:
[image]

Entity definitions:

```
@Entity(name = "Trade")
@Table(name = "trade", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"trade_num", "fund", "stop_date"}))
public class Trade {
    @EmbeddedId
    private TradePK tradePK;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "fund", referencedColumnName = "fund"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "cusip", referencedColumnName = "cusip"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "trade_num", referencedColumnName = "trade_num"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "start_date", referencedColumnName = "pos_date"),
//            @JoinColumn(name = "pos_date", referencedColumnName = "start_date"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "stop_date", referencedColumnName = "stop_date")
    })
    private TradeDetails tradeDetails;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
}

@Embeddable
public class TradePK  implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "start_date", nullable = false)
    private Date startDate;

    @Column(name = "stop_date", nullable = false)
    private Date stopDate;

    @Column(name = "fund")
    private int fund;

    @Column(name = "cusip", nullable = false)
    private String cusip;

    @Column(name = "trade_num")
    private int tradeNum;
}

@Entity(name = "TradeDetails")
@Table(name = "trade_details")
public class TradeDetails {
    @EmbeddedId
    private TradeDetailsPK tradeDetailsPK;

    @Column(name = "amount")
    private float amount;

    @Column(name = "broker_name")
    private String brokerName;
}

@Embeddable
public class TradeDetailsPK implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "fund")
    private int fund;

    @Column(name = "pos_date", nullable = false)
    private Date posDate;

    @Column(name = "cusip", nullable = false)
    private String cusip;

    @Column(name = "trade_num")
    private int tradeNum;

    @Column(name = "stop_date", nullable = false)
    private Date stopDate;
}
```

And this is my repository class:

```
@Repository
public interface TradeRepository extends JpaRepository<Trade, TradePK> {
    String QUERY = "select T.* " +
            "from trade T, trade_details TD " +
            "where T.fund = :fund " +
            "and T.cusip = :cusip " +
            "and TD.fund = T.fund " +
            "and TD.cusip = T.cusip " +
            "and TD.trade_num = T.trade_num";

    @Query(value = QUERY, nativeQuery = true)
    List<Trade> findTradeByFundAndCusip(@Param("fund") int fund, @Param("cusip") String cusip);
}
```

So the issue here is the call to `tradeRepository.findTradeByFundAndCusip(fund, cusip)` fails. The exception stacktrace is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.rdm.learnasync.model.tradedetails.TradeDetails. Expected: class com.rdm.learnasync.model.tradedetails.TradeDetailsPK, got class com.rdm.learnasync.model.trade.TradePK; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.rdm.learnasync.model.tradedetails.TradeDetails. Expected: class com.rdm.learnasync.model.tradedetails.TradeDetailsPK, got class com.rdm.learnasync.model.trade.TradePK
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:257)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:149)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy82.findTradeByFundAndCusip(Unknown Source)
    at com.rdm.learnasync.service.TradeService.find(TradeService.java:21)
    at com.rdm.learnasync.LearnAsyncApplication.main(LearnAsyncApplication.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.rdm.learnasync.model.tradedetails.TradeDetails. Expected: class com.rdm.learnasync.model.tradedetails.TradeDetailsPK, got class com.rdm.learnasync.model.trade.TradePK
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1536)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:409)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy88.getResultList(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:126)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:154)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:142)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:618)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.rdm.learnasync.model.tradedetails.TradeDetails. Expected: class com.rdm.learnasync.model.tradedetails.TradeDetailsPK, got class com.rdm.learnasync.model.trade.TradePK
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.checkIdClass(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1176)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1041)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:687)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:464)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1179)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1028)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:964)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2838)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2820)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2652)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2647)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2131)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1163)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1530)
    ... 29 more
```

I think the issue is with the `@OneToOne`. The reason I say this is when I change the relationship to `@OneToMany`, I am able to fetch the data. But I dont understand whats the issue with `@OneToOne`. I cannot fathom how id mismatch is even possible `Provided id of the wrong type for class` ?

Note:

1. The table structure cannot be changed, the state of the database
   cannot be changed.
2. Also, I am using lombok library - Used `@Data`, `@AllArgsConstructor` and `NoArgsConstructor` in the model classes.
3. Added my sample code to github:
   https://github.com/rahul118bbsr/LearningHibernate

Comment: Since the method `findTradeByFundAndCusip` returns a `List<Trade>` the query should start with `select T from trade T, trade_details TD` instead of `select * from ...`; also, is there a good reason why you are using a native query?

Comment: Apologies, oversight while copy and paste. It was `T.*` but somehow it got modified to `*`. Changed it to `*` here and in my sample code. I see the same problem anyways

Comment: @Jesper - No I am new to hibernate, learning it from the hibernate docs. So I started off with native SQL, but my plan is to leverage spring-data-jpa's method like `public List<Trade> findTradeByFundAndCusip(int fund, String cusip);`